# update manger on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: updates, update-manager

Requires installation of untrusted packages 
this state appear when do update

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xmFh.png

Answer (score 0):

Try opening terminal and typing

> sudo apt-get install libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 network-manager-whoopsie

and then try again.